# Normalising data for simple linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent, normalization

Consider a simple linear regression problem where:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,100,200]
Y=  [2,4,6,8,10,200,400]
```

Clearly, the relationship is of the form $y=2x$; While trying to solve this using gradient descent based method using MSE loss, it never converges and gives a $W$ (slope of the line) that is too different from the actual value of $2$.

At the same time, my solution works perfectly when the $X$ are small evenly spaced values like $X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]$. But the solution does not work for large values of $X$ like $X = [100,200,300,400]$ or unevenly spaced $X$ like $X = [1,2,3,4,100,200]$

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array ([1,2,3,4,5,100,200])
Y= X*2
W = np.array ([0.0]) # initialize the weight to be 0

def forward (X, W):

  return W*X

def backward (Y_predicted, X, Y):
  dW = np.matmul (X.T, Y_predicted - Y ).mean()
  return dW

lr = 0.01
n_epochs = 15
for epoch in range (n_epochs):
  prediction = forward (X,W)
  dW = backward (prediction, X, Y)
  W = W - lr*dW
  print (W)
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradient descent works perfectly fine when your features have large values, but you might have to use a smaller learning rate. In this case, simply decreasing the learning rate to 0.00001 allows the model to converge to the correct result of W=2.
Generally input features are normalized (e.g. to a range of 0-1) to help the model converge more easily.

Comment: Yes a learning rate of 0.00001 helps, but it took nearly 700 epochs to converge. And if the X is changed to  say X = np.array ([100,200,300,400,500,600]), even the learning rate of 0.00001 wont help; the weight W becomes nan within 60 epochs. I believe the trick is to standardise data at all times.

Comment: I only needed less than 15 epochs to get the model to converge to a weight of close to 2. It would indeed be easiest to standardize your data, or use something like [gradient clipping](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-gradient-clipping-b8e815cdfb48) to prevent the gradients to explode. Clipping the gradients allows me to get the model to converge using a learning rate of 0.01 for both input arrays.